# Creating a list of lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to find a code that transforms a list of lists into a dictionary. Lets say I have a list that is

```
list_one = [['id1', 'id2', id3', 'id4', 'id5'],
            ['1', 'Cat', '400', 'Fur', '50'],
            ['2', 'Dog', '500', 'Smelly', '60']]
```

The dictionary should have keys to number each list in dictionaries in this format

```
new_dict = {1.0: {'id1': 1,
                 'id2': 'Cat',
                 'id3': 400,
                 'id4': 'Fur',
                 'id5': 50},
            2.0: {'id1': 2,
                  'id2': 'Dog',
                  'id3': 500,
                  'id4': 'Smelly'
                  'id5': 60}
```

Can such a conversion be done in list comprehension or through a for loop?

Comment: Seems very simple, so why not try implementing it yourself instead of spending potentially more time looking for ready-made code online?

Comment: in our target dict, why are the keys `1.0 ,2.0` etc. Why decimals? what is the physical significance?

Comment: To @Srini 's point, storing the keys as `floats` incurs extra overhead for no particular reason. Just store as `int`, it is smaller (from a data perspective) and makes it a bit easier to look up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple dict-comprehension using enumerate:

```
list_one = [['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5'],
            ['1', 'Cat', '400', 'Fur', '50'],
            ['2', 'Dog', '500', 'Smelly', '60']]

new_dict = {float(i): dict(zip(list_one[0], items)) 
            for i, items in enumerate(list_one[1:], start=1)}

print(new_dict)
```

results in

```
{1.0: {'id1': '1', 'id2': 'Cat', 'id3': '400', 'id4': 'Fur', 'id5': '50'}, 
 2.0: {'id1': '2', 'id2': 'Dog', 'id3': '500', 'id4': 'Smelly', 'id5': '60'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your use case, the keys are the first list in your list, and the objects are the rest. You can zip them together and create that dictionary like so:

```
ks, objs = list_one[0], list_one[1:]

myobjects = {i: dict(zip(ks, l)) for i,l in enumerate(objs)}
```

`zip` will take the element-by-element pairs and create tuples like `(x, y)` and `dict` will make `{x: y}` from that tuple. The docs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with third party library pandas

```
import pandas as pd
{float(k):v for k,v in enumerate(pd.DataFrame(list_one[1:],columns=list_one[0]).to_dict('records'),1)}
```

Comment: op said nothing about using pandas

Comment: @Srini to be fair: the OP said nothing against using pandas....

Comment: @hiroprotagonist true. But the original version of the answer did not make it clear that pandas was being used either. I just wanted to highlight that too :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
>>> new_dict = {float(i): {list_one[0][j]:val for j,val in enumerate(list_one[i])} for i in range(1,len(list_one))}
>>> new_dict
 {1.0: {'id1': '1', 'id2': 'Cat', 'id3': '400', 'id4': 'Fur', 'id5': '50'},
 2.0: {'id1': '2', 'id2': 'Dog', 'id3': '500', 'id4': 'Smelly', 'id5': '60'}}
```